# Python and php side by side

Tags: php, python

I'm reading how to write idiomatic python,

http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

which covers essential Python idioms and techniques, but sometimes I find it hard to follow and would appreciate if there are equivalents in php which would go side by side and explain the python code.

Comment: I'm elated that you're trying to write idiomatic python -- However, I'm having a bit of a hard time knowing what you're asking for here.  If you want someone to provide a list of side-by-side python/php idioms, it's probably not going to happen.  I would assume that many idioms don't translate that easily.

Comment: I'm aware that php would produce more code for the same task, but would also clarify things for people with different background.

Comment: It's not a matter of there being more code in one language or the other.  The problem is that this question is too general to be answered meaningfully.  If you're looking for a particular idiom that's maybe OK (although I find that SO users aren't usually very excited about code translation).  If you make a translation yourself and you're wondering if it's idiomatic, that's a great question for CodeReview (IMHO).

Comment: PHP is designed as a template language first and everything else second. So you're not going to find things like `$_GET` in Python, and you're not going to find the really good stuff like list comprehensions and argument unpacking in PHP. 

I suggest you fire up a Python interpreter and experiment with it, you're better off learning it that way than with PHP, I think.

Comment: When you find it hard to follow as in you don't understand it, you can [**ask a new question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about just that. That is to say: One question you have corresponds to one [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would *not be useful* to compare **PHP** and **Python** side by side because the two are very different.  **PHP** *is a web language* and **Python** is a *general purpose language*.  As a general purpose language, Python can certainly be used on the web but in order to do so one *employs or creates a framework*, with some popular ones being Django and Flask.  Natively, in the core Python language, there is no way to access GET and POST data.  **Since PHP is a web programming language, $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_SERVER, $_SESSION, and $_REQUEST are simple built in ways to access arrays of data, most of which is passed from the client to the server** (with the exception being parts of $_SERVER and of course $_SESSION).  Python, on the other hand, has no equivalent counterpart.

Python also *does not natively provide session management*.  There are some good session libraries out there, but Python is not an 'all in one' like PHP is. In Python there are many 3rd party libraries and modules that are available as open source.  PHP is also open source and has **PECL**, the *PHP Extension Community Library*.  **PHP** has a *very impressive list of built in functions*.  PHP natively provides many functions that manipulate strings and arrays.  Python provides some native functions, but in order to implement all of the equivalent PHP functions in Python you must know the algorithm and write the code yourself.

**PHP** is a very popular web programming language for a good reason - it is extremely powerful *out of the box* and allows for very fast development times.  Outside of web development it is very limited in the tasks that it can accomplish.  **Facebook** wrote *HipHop* which translates their **PHP** code into **C++** to improve performance.  PHP can also be used on the command line, although it is my opinion that **PHP** is *not the best tool for the job* when programming administrative tasks on the command line.

**Python** *is not an 'out of the box, all in one* programming language.  Comparing the link you posted to PHP is impractical as the core PHP language is much larger than the core Python language and many complimentary features of PHP would be left out.